# Casts between different class trees ins C++

Tags: c++, casting

The following code seems to work with the compilers (clang, g++ on both, Linux and Mac OS) I tried, but is it guaranteed to always do what one would expect?

```
struct A {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct A2 {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : public A2 {
  void foo() {
    printf("test\n");
  }
};

int main() {
  B* b = new B;
  ((A*)b)->foo();
}
```

I realize this is bad practice and one should not do this, but does it work generally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not bad practice: It **doesn't** *work*. It will do *something* allright. Not unlikely, crashing. It is all allowed since you are invoking [*unspecified behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior). **Edit** You might consult your compiler technical documentation (*refer to ABI*) to find compiler-specific *extensions* that you might rely on.

Try using

```
static_cast<A*>(b)    // invalid static cast (compile error)
dynamic_cast<A*>(b)   // returns null pointer value (runtime)
```

What you are doing is effectively

- `reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)`

and the results are entirely <strike>your own responsibility</strike> *implementation-defined*.

**Edit** To Nawaz: relevant standards passage: § 5.2.10, clause

> **`7.`** A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer to a different object type.<sup>69</sup> When a
>   *prvalue* `v` of type “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to *cv* T2”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment
>   requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1. Converting a *prvalue* of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. ***The result of any
>   other such pointer conversion is unspecified***.

Comment: It worked with all compilers I tested (clang, g++) on Linux as well as OS X. You're saying this is just by chance?

Comment: @lucasclemente: No. I'm saying it is _undefined by the standard_. Chance has got nothing to do with it (chances are good that compilers will generate identical layout for identical classes. [C++ does not protect againt Machiavelli attacks](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm) - see Herb Sutter). However, this violates the ODR in a rather extreme way and therefore it cannot be relied upon. In any implementation.

Comment: If `((A*)b)` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)`, then is using `reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)` an undefined behaviour? Why? `reinterpret_cast<char const*>(0x12334)` invokes undefined behavior?

Comment: @Nawaz: **in this context** it is _effectively_ equivalent to the `reinterpret_cast`. Your `char const*` cast has nothing to do with this. I haven't stated that all uses of reinterpret casts are undefined (although _many are_) - and I find the fact that you seem to suggest that I did very surprising.

Comment: @sehe: So you are saying the alignment will not generally be the same? That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @sehe: So you mean the usage of `reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)` invokes undefined behaviour? Does the Standard say so?

Comment: @Nawaz: to the best of my knowledge: Yes.

Comment: @sehe: Now, I started to doubt. :|

Comment: @lucasclemente: No. I said, though alignment _may_ generally be the same, you _cannot_ rely on that. I think that is pretty clear.

Comment: @sehe: So it is actually *unspecified*, rather than *undefined*.

Comment: @Nawaz: touché! Amended the wordings in my answer. Toned down on the UB samples too

Answer (score 6):

If one would expect the undefined behavior, then it is guaranteed.

Comment: If `((A*)b)` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)`, then is using `reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)` an undefined behaviour? Why? `reinterpret_cast<char const*>(0x12334)` invokes undefined behavior?

Comment: Why did you left out the `->foo()` part?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Consider that also. I just didn't type to make it short.

Comment: Well, then define the behavior of casting anything to something and dereferencing it (including your 0x12334 example).

Answer (score 3):

If you use C++-style cast, then you would see the problem immediately:

```
(static_cast<A*>(b))->foo();  //compile-time error
(dynamic_cast<A*>(b))->foo(); //runtime error
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/LZjrx (compile-time error)
Demo : http://ideone.com/ePIfO (runtime error)

Since `static_cast` gives compilation error, the story ends right then, at compilation time. When `dynamic_cast`,  then casting returns null, on which you trying to invoke `foo`, so you get runtime error.

Even if you don't know which casts to use, these two casts give enough confidence to doubt the code, while the usage of `reinterpret_cast` is so rare, that I don't even consider here.

Comment: Do him justice - he *does* see the problem, he just underestimates it or doesn't see it in all it's glory. (that is not to disagree).

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I see he does see the problem. I'm rather explaining the benefits of using C++-style cast.

Comment: Yes, I was just making a smart-ace comment about the "you would see the problem immediately".

Comment: hmmm I don't usually call a segfault a _runtime error_. I'd call a `std::runtime_error` a runtime error.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: And I said that because OP asked this (even after knowing the problem) : *"I realize this is bad practice and one should not do this, **but does it work generally?***"

Comment: @sehe: Alright. By runtime error, I obviously mean, logical error in the code. Now you would call `std::logic_error` a logical error? :P

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, segfault happens at run time :)

Comment: The funny thing is that it actually does work with all the compilers I tested. That's why I asked the question, to see whether there is something beneath it.

Comment: @lucasclemente, seriously, "does work" means happened to invoke some behavior that matches your expectations based on the information outside the standards. How can you seriously guarantee that?

Comment: My question was whether this is actually outside of the standard or whether it isn't. I don't want to be using something outside of the standard, obviously. But thinking about where the compiler places the functions in the assembler when `A` and `A1` are equal, I wasn't so sure whether this might actually work.